# SQL Get most recent date from table to be included in a VIEW with inner join

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, datetime, join

[image: sample table]

I have this issue and I cant find out a correct solution. The following image shows a table where I have different records going in. The keys for the records are `RID` and `NAME`, and I would like to create a query that returns only most recent dates from both keys (marked in grey in the image).

I would appreciate this comunity help in trying to make it work, I have already tried joining with it self and try to get the Date1 > Date2 without success.

I solve this by using this query:

```
SELECT  *
 FROM     <table> as o
 inner join
 (
 select  RID, NAME, max(CREATED) as CREATED from <table> group by  RID, NAME
 ) as t on t.NAME=o.NAME and t.RID=o.RID and o.CREATED=t.CREATED
 order by ID
```

I would appreciate if you can find a better solution to it so I can also get the ID in the query?

Comment: please provide your sql also. it's very easy to find out the problem in your SQL

Comment: images are blocked in my domain unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since maximum `ID` is related to maximum `CREATED` you can use aggregates to find maximum `CREATED` and `ID` for each distinct pair of `RID, NAME`:

```
select RID, NAME, max(ID), max(CREATED) from <your-table-name> group by RID, NAME
```

Comment: ok.. this help me really to find the answer, I also need the ID in the query, and as soon as it is included, then the RID, NAME reference is lost.

Comment: Is it that `ID` is always greater when `CREATED` is greater? That is for maximum `ID` the `CREATED` is maximum as well?

Comment: yes.. it is greater.. but I dont like to rely on something like this... i wuold like your query to find the id that belongs to that row. that would be just great!

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by using this query:

```
SELECT  *  FROM     <table> as o  inner join  (  select  RID, NAME,
max(CREATED) as CREATED from <table> group by  RID, NAME  ) as t on
t.NAME=o.NAME and t.RID=o.RID and o.CREATED=t.CREATED  order by ID
```

I would appreciate if you can find a better solution to it so I can also get the ID in the query?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to realy on max(ID) being in the same row as max(CREATED) and also want a better performance, you can use ROW_NUMBER analytical function.

That way you can return all columns of the row.

```
SELECT  ID, RID, NAME, CREATED,
ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
    PARTITION BY RID, NAME
    ORDER BY CREATED DESC
)
FROM <table> 
WHERE row_number = 1;
```

We first rank all rows of the group and take the first row from each of the groups. Since the order by is DESC, the first row is the most recent one.